# primefaces datatable selection checkbox issue

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

i'm facing a problem with prime-faces data table multiple selection.whenever i select some records and perform action for the first time ,it wont send back any records, then if i sort any columns or click 2 or 3 times values are passed correctly .could it be a ajax issue? or any property need to attach to the list?

```
 <p:dataTable id="StatusSearch" var="item" rowIndexVar="rowStatusSearch" value="#{StatusAction.listBondLocationEBeans"
    selection="#{StatusAction.listBEeans}" rowKey="#{item.LocationId}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

ActionBean:

```
private LocationEBean[] listBEeans;
```

Comment: please enable your firebug and check whether you have any client side java script errors. then check your code with a simple page and simple bean without extra stuff. and please share some more code here from your bean and facelet page.

Comment: Thanks @Heidarzedeh,i found the problem with immediate=true in my submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the problem,in my action button i used "immediate=true" property after i remove that it's working normally.